# Vibrating through beams from circulator pump and at strange times

Tags: heating, water-circulating-heating

I have a [grundfos alpha 2 circulator pump](https://www.plumbcenter.co.uk/wcsstore7.00.922.258/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/images/products/AssetPush/DTP_AssetPushHighRes/std.lang.all/ti/on/Grundfos_Alpha2_Installation.pdf) which for the last two years (since I moved into the house) when the heating turns on makes a vibrating noise. This vibrating noise I believe is then vibrating through some of the pipes, which in turn reverberate through the wooden structure of the house. To the point where my neighbours complain about the noise.

Some useful points:

- When heating is on and circulating water then the vibrating noise happens
- Circulation seems to happen at weird times in the night, I can't confirm this (because I am asleep) but the neighbour thinks it comes on at 3 & 5am. 5am one may make sense due to the heating coming on.
- It is installed in the correct position and orientation from what I can tell from reading through the manual
- There is zero air in the system, I have attempted to drain the radiators but the moment I undo the bolt liquid comes out. I believe this is an effect of the "self venting" alpha 2.

**My Question**

Is there anything with regards to this I can debug, and potentially get rid of this vibrating. I'm keen not to play with anything too serious without a professional but I do not know if this is a common issue or not.

Comment: How is you hear controlled? Thermostat?  Setback?  How far away is the complaining neighbor? (Trying to get a sense of how noisey and large of a nuscance this is)

Comment: in a terraced UK house, you can hear it from all rooms in the house. Thermostat setting, with a doobry in the airing cupboard with timing settings which are not set to come on in the middle of the night.